# Datastudio: REGEXP_Extract the project no within url structure

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I want to extract project no between url structure.
How could i write regular expression to extract project no?

> landingpage : web/campaign/detail/169359?https://_refer_section_st=PersonalCurator_0

> answer : 169359

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT (landingpage, ??)
```

I have tried and got an answer as below

```
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(landingpage , '^/web/campaign/[^/]+/([^/]+)/' )
```

> reply : 169359?https:

[image]

Comment: Replace `([^/]+)` with `([^/?]+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/l1Qoyf/1

Comment: Could i extract 6 digit as well from dirty structure? 
i have found another ones to be fixed. You can refer to the pic by clikcing enter image description here

Comment: So, you only want the digits? Use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(landingpage, '^web/campaign/[^/]+/(\d+)')`

Comment: In line with your advice, How could i extract the digits from where there are 3 different url sturctures.

1> /web/campaign/detail/169359? 
2> /web/store/detail/74? 
3> /web/wcomingsoon/rwd/195164

Answer (score -1):

You may try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(landingpage , 'detail/(\\d+)')
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thanks. it works. 
But furtheremore, What if i want to extract digits from where there are 3 different structures? How could i use it?  

1> /web/campaign/detail/169359?
2> /web/store/detail/74?
3> /web/wcomingsoon/rwd/195164


I have tried it. but failed. 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(landing page, 'detail/(\\d+)|rwd/(\\d+)')

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TQycH89.png Try: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(landingpage , '(?:rwd|detail)/(\\d+)')`